# How do I access route parameter values from `HttpRequest` in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions

We have a precompiled C# Azure Function. It's a HTTP triggered function and has required route parameters. How do I access the route parameter values from the `HttpRequest` object? We have a few different private methods in the same class file that already use the `HttpRequest` instance that is passed from the public Run() method.

I know I could add a parameter to the public method's signature with the same name as the route parameter and then pass that value to the various private methods. But I already have the HttpRequest object passed where it needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, I think we need to add the parameter to the public method's signature with the same name. But as a workaround, we can get the path from `HttpRequest` and then substring the parameter which you want from it. Please refer to my code below:

[image]